# Проблема с отображением текста кнопки

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Что нужно исправить (добавить) в верстке, чтобы было как на изображении снизу?

Спасибо!

[Оригинал](http://jsfiddle.net/remv8uay/3/)

```css
a.class1 {
  width: 155px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}

a.class2 {
  width: 75px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}

.main-block-1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10;
  width: 155px;
  float: left;
}

.main-block-1>li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.main-block-1 a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main-block-1 .services1 {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
}

.main-block-1>li:hover .services1 {
  display: block;
}

.services1>li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.services1 a {
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 10px;
}

li {
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #40382D;
}

li:hover {
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background: #fff;
}

li:hover a {
  color: #40382D;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-block-1">
  <li><a class="class1" href="#block1">БЛОК 1</a>
    <ul class="services1">
      <li><a class="class2" href="#serv">Услуги</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!--services-->
  </li>
  <!--блок-1-->
</ul>
<!--main-block 1-->
```

[image: как должно быть]

Comment: Ну вообще. `li:hover .class2 { color: white;  }` ... но по хорошему надо переписать с классами... из-за li идет страшная путанница (и не факт, что там нужен ul )

Comment: Все как на картинке вроде... Не понятно, что автору надо...

Comment: Вы уверены, что всё как на картинке? @Air

Comment: Проблема с белым текстом?

Comment: после совета пользователя был добавлен li:hover .class2 { color: white; } шрифт (он же текст) "Услуги"  стал появляется при наведении на БЛОК 1, но! при наведении на ссылку Услуги - белый фон. Текст Услуги должен быть темного цвета - что и видно на прикрепленном изображении. @Air

Comment: если Вас, @OPTIMUSPRIME не затруднит - покажите на простом примере, как "переписать с классами"?

Answer (score 0):

Ну классы не принципиальны. Я это к тому написал, что где-то на странице тоже может встретиться li... что может заставить вернуться и переписать этот код. А с уникальными классами, которые встречаются только тут - будет надежнее)

Не скопировал все ваши стили, а оставил всё самое необходимое, сверху сможете уже добавить. В простом случае это выглядит так:

[JsFiddle (здесь может быть удобнее смотреть)](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/gbk01hLc/)

Писал одной строчкой, чтобы легче было смотреть на всю картину. Вместо `height: 30px;` добавил строгий размер текста `20px и padding: 5px 0;`, что дало тот же эффект высоты, но поставило текст в центре. Здесь "5px 0" означает "5 пикселей сверху и снизу и 0 справа и слева"

```css
/* Селектор-звездочка означает "Всё". Его используют только при крайней необходимости */
/* Добавлено чисто чтобы легче вникать, кто-чей родственник и где находится*/
* {border:1px solid;}

.main-block-1 a {text-decoration: none;}

.mama { width: 155px; font-size: 20px;}
.a-1 {color: #fff; background-color: #40382d; padding: 5px 0px; 
      display: block; width: 100%; text-align: center; border-radius: 5px; }
.a-2 {color: #fff; background-color: #40382d; padding: 5px 0px; 
      display: block; width: 100%; text-align: center; border-radius: 5px; }
.bubu {display: none;}
/* При наведении на общий блок - перекрашиваем главный пункт*/
.mama:hover .a-1 {background-color: #fff; color: #40382d;}
.mama:hover .bubu {display: block;} /* делаем подпункты видимыми */
/* А при наведении на сами подпункты - в свою очередь перекрашиваем их */
.a-2:hover { background-color: #fff; color: #40382d; }
```

```html
<ul class="main-block-1">
  <li class="mama">
    <a class="a-1" href="#block1">БЛОК 1</a>
    <ul class="services1">
      <li class="bubu">
        <a class="a-2" href="#serv">Услуги</a>
      </li>
      <li class="bubu">
        <a class="a-2" href="#serv">Бубу</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

А если есть необходимость выровнять подпункты по левому краю... возможно вообще полезнее будет заменить ul на div...

Comment: Премного благодарен! @OPTIMUSPRIME